# Running node command with Process results in error: The process with PID xxxx (child process of PID xxxx) could not be terminated

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, puppeteer

I am attempting to kick off a node command via C# code using System.Diagnostics.Process and System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo but encounter this error on my test system (no such error on the development system).

Output of this command is piped to a text file and that is where the error is written.

```
string filename = string.Format("\"{0}\"", nodePath);
string arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" -u \"{1}\" -p \"{2}\" > \"{3}\"",
        scriptPath, uName, pword, outFileName);
ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = filename,
    Arguments = arguments,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
Process p = new Process
{
    StartInfo = si
};
string statusMessage = String.Format("Executing command: '{0}'", si.FileName);
Logger.LogDomInfo(statusMessage);
bool started = p.Start();
```

As I mentioned before, this runs just fine on the development machine but fails on the test environment with this error:

```
ERROR: The process with PID 4880 (child process of PID 5440) could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

Comment: What is the value of `scriptPath`? If it is a path to the file containing the script, maybe NodeJS isn't registered for `.js` files. You might try passing the path to `node.exe` and then `scriptPath` as the first argument.

Comment: Whoops, had a formatting issue that was cutting off the top line.

The path to the `node.exe` is set as the FileName property of the `ProcessStartInfo` instance. 

scriptPath is the full path to the `.js` file so the end result would be the same as manually running `> node.exe script.js` from the command prompt.